# information about licensing and patching SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, license, patching, ssas-2016

I have one server for data warehousing, and it has 2 instances of `SSAS` (`SQL SERVER Analysis Services`).

The data warehouses are not that big, less that 200GB, and I backup the whole thing on a daily basis.

Now they have asked me to patch\upgrade it:

> Thank you yes, this indicates it is a 2016 SP1. The reason I ask is
>   that, as I indicated on Friday, when we tested the creation of
>   measures (e.g. year-to-date net applications) in Power BI from a live
>   connection to your Analysis Server, this caused unexpected errors. Our
>   research shows that this is very probably caused by your Analysis
>   Server version, and the solution is to install a Cumulative Update
>   [(CU) 3 for SQL Server 2016 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4019916/cumulative-update-3-for-sql-server-2016-sp1), or a more recent CU (as you can see in
>   the list on the left of the page, these go up to CU 11). As far as we
>   know these are free to download, but you may need to ask your
>   consultants for help.

I wish I had different servers for LIVE and TEST environments.
Where can I find information about the costs of licensing involved for a small server just to run a `SSAS` instance?

I am talking about a simple, single, machine, with windows server 2012 R2 and the latest `ssas`.

Also, patching for `SSAS` is anyhow different from `sql server`?

I find licensing costs a tricky topic sometimes, with not-so-clear or contradictory information around.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing. Please read the meta discussion [Are licensing questions within our scope?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/487/15356). Any licensing advice given by non-Microsoft employee could put the author of the answer in difficult situation. Please contact your Microsoft representative or licensing vendor to receive valid licensing information.

Comment: Sorry, now down-vote from my side. I just voted to close this question as off-topic and added a reason. Apart from that, patching is the same for Analysis Services as if it were just for the SQL Server instance. I know because I have to install Analysis Services on 10 instances and then upgrade them to the same Service Pack level as the SQL Server instances, they are running on.

Comment: The statement you made last in your question is the best reason to contact your Microsoft representative and/or license vendor: _"...I find licensing costs a tricky topic sometimes, with not-so-clear or contradictory information around..."_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments (specially [hot2use)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/15356/hot2use)I realised that [Licensing is NOT our scope](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/487/are-licensing-questions-within-our-scope) and I need to contact [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/contactus/) in order to clarify those matters.

I also understood that patching `SSAS` is patching the `sql server` and I will include it in my normal schedule.

[How to obtain the latest service pack for SQL Server 2016?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3177534/how-to-obtain-the-latest-service-pack-for-sql-server-2016)

Applying cumulative updates:
[image]

and after applying SP2 the new version of my `SSAS` is:
[image]

Answer (score -7):

At the notion of sounding sarcastic, I will actually answer the qeustion you DO ask. Note that Licensing specifics are off topic here, so the answer is general.

> Where can I find information about the costs of licensing involved for a small 
>   server just to run a SSAS instance?

At the same place you find the cost of licensing SQL Server in general, as it is part of SQL Server.

THAT SAID: development environments are often better licensed via MSDN.

> patching for SSAS is anyhow different from sql server?

Patching for SSAS IS patching for SQL Server. SSAS is a module in SQL Server.

> I find licensing costs a tricky topic sometimes

Then learn them. Most people find databases confiusing, you still can learn them. As a development lead (or whatever) tasked with that - it is your job to know your way around those. I would suggest taking some months off and looking into an alternative career in medicine or law - THEN you will start looking at stuff that is "not so clear and sometimes contradictory". IT is actually trivial if you spend some time in it, even licensing, compared to becoming a lawyer. Part of the job. And we can not help you - licensing costs MAY well be company specific depending what programs you are in.

Now, if you check SQL Server build numbers, yours are OUTDATED. Current is 13.0.5216.0, September 21 2018. Yours is an update August 2017. Not even current service pack level. Definitely needs patching, and definitely needs a separate system to validate. I generally make it a rule to update quarterly minimum.